# resources for making a 2d sprite?

Tags: sprite

I am making a 2d game, can you post link- tutorials for making a 2d game sprites?, and tutorial for browser game development?

I will be really helpfull

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29)'s an article with quite a few details

[This site](http://www.sprites-inc.co.uk/) also has some sprite-related resources, and the forums have some guides from a number of experienced people.

If you are wanting to learn about making 2D sprites, the best advice I can give is to learn from the hard work of others.  Find a game with sprites that you can edit, and start by modifying the existing sprites (a simple recolor is an easy starting point).  Then you can move on to larger sprite modifications (shape, size, etc), "swapping" sprites between games, creating a simple game and using sprites that you "borrowed" from an existing game, etc.

Comment: Just linking to a general Wiki article is not a particularly good answer, but there is one link at the bottom which seems promising: http://www.themechanicalmaniacs.com/guides/spriteguide.php

Comment: Just asking "can you post link- tutorials for making a 2d game sprites?" is not a particularly good question... bta's answer was fine for the level of detph asked in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this problem recently.

In the old days, sprites were hand-drawn pixel by pixel. This works well for flat 2D games (side-scrollers, cartoon adventure games, Z-axis top-down, and such), particularly if they are in the 320x200 resolution. Some examples of gorgeous hand-drawn sprite games are the Sierra and Lucas Arts adventure games, Disney's jump&runs, Capcom's fighter games, the Tyrian/Raptor-style top-down scrollers, and the early RTS games (C&C, WC1).
Some games, like Prince of Persia and Mortal Combat, used sprites from animated actors. That produced fluid motion, but looked 'flat'.

Between the mid-90s and the early-00s, character/item sprite-drawing was done by taking stills of 3D objects. Practically every 2D RTS game since around Age of Empires 1 did that. AFAIK Diablo, Baldur's Gate, Divine Divinity, and other such RPG games did the same. This is the reason those games came on so many CDs - they were chock-full of content.
This approach looks great (not flat, but "2.5D") but takes a lot of hard-drive space. Also, whereas you could produce hand-drawn sprites in Paint, the 2.5D ones require 3Ds Max (or equivalent).
One problem that arises with this approach is the combinatorial explosion in costume design (i.e. if you want animate a character in three different coats with three different hats and three different pairs of pants, you need 27 distinct animation). The solution to this, as seen in Diablo II and Baldur's Gate, is rag-dolling - you produce different sprites for every part of the body. This takes a lot of work. Blizzard made their own tools to produce their sprites, but I'm not sure there are sprite rag-dolling tools in the open.

More recently, most games are 3D. Many actually look worse than the old 2.5D ones, because a simple 3D model can animate well in sprites, but poorly in real-time 3D. The difference is that between a glamor shot of a celebrity, taken from a certain distance in certain lighting and then worked-over in photoshop, and the appearance of the same celebrity in real-life (which may not be as glamorous).

I wonder if there are 3D Object -> Sprite programs. I know of one (don't remember the name at the moment), but are there others? At the very least I'm sure there are scripts for Maya and 3ds Max that take shots of an animated 3D object from different angles. Does anyone know more on this?

Answer (score 0):

To make a 2D game sprite:

Open up paint.  Paint a picture.  Save as a bmp.  You now have a 1 frame sprite.  You can add meta data to this in code if needed for hotspot, collision info, etc.  If you want it to animate, create a bunch of bmps and display them 1 at a time at whatever speed you want to animate them at.

No need for a tutorial link for something like this.  Or, you can download any one of thousands of sprite editors that do the above stuff in one place.